BigQuery dataset shown empty in PowerBI
I'm having trouble using BigQuery as a data source in PowerBI because it doesn't detect one of my dataset's content. This dataset contains 502 tables, so I figured that's maybe why tables don't appear unlike other datasets.
I'm using the BigQuery connector and everything works perfectly except for this highly populated dataset. Did you ever faced this kind of issue, or do you know where that could come from?
Thanks for your help
